# lstinline error "ended by EOL" in dtsyntax

Tags: listings

I'm using the package `dtsyntax` to highlight code text based on listings. For in-line annotation they make a new command `\modelica{ }` based on lstinline as follows :

```
\newcommand{\modelica}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily,language=modelica]|#1|}
```

But when i use this as follows

```
this is a test concerning highlighting \modelica{"modelica"} in LaTeX ...
```

I get the following error which i can not trace back :

```
Package Listings Error: lstinline ended by EOL.
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: whereas '\modelica{modelica}' works fine, so the problem seems to concern the use of ' " ' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the one language in your document, you could add the following to your preamble:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, language=modelica}
\lstMakeShortInline{|}
```

And then you can just write `|"modelica"|` and that should work. (I haven't tested this because I don't have dtsyntax)

The `\lstset` macro sets up global formatting options for all instances of `\lstinline` and `lstlistings` and similar environments. The `\lstMakeShortVerb` is optional, and allows you to specify a symbol that can be quickly used to enclose text to be "`lstinline`d".

The "ended by EOL" error suggests that the problem has something to do with linebreaks, but if the code is as you say it is, and if removing the `"` makes things work, then I am stumped...

Comment: it indeed (only) depends on `"` which defines the look of the text as this denotes a `string` in the code, if i put something in front it and behind it as `a "test";`, it also works perfectly fine ...

Comment: That is odd. And might have something to do with `"` sometimes being active. (I'm out of my depth here, we'll have to wait for someone smarter to answer this one, I'm afraid...)

Comment: @ruben: It'd be better to wait for a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).